# Why build a large spaceship when a small one will do?

Tags: freeciv

If I am aiming for a space victory, why should I build a large spaceship when I can build a small one instead? A small spaceship has three advantages over a large spaceship:

- It takes less time to build.
- It takes less resources to build.
- It has a shorter travel time to Alpha Centauri.

This is a large spaceship:

[image: Freeciv large spaceship]

Why should I build a large spaceship when the small spaceship below requires less resources to build, and has a shorter travel time?

[image: Freeciv small spaceship]

Comment: 2 words : Bragging Rights.

Answer (score 2):

Having a bigger spaceship means having more population in it.

Population is a variable that affect scoring formula.

In some games, when you reach 2000 CE, the game stops and the player with the highest score wins.

Comment: Is this for Freeciv or is this for Civilization?

Comment: I found this info on a Freeciv forum ... but I guess it could also work on Civ1.
I am more acquainted with CivNet personally.
The fact is that more population gives you more points, regardless of the winning condition.